# How can the Starter Set wizard have five skills?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, wizard, elf, pregenerated-characters

I ran out of time making my own Elven character, so I grabbed the pre-made one from the starter set.  Then I realized that the skill selection is impossible.  The included High Elf Wizard comes with proficiency in 5 skills.  Arcana, Insight, Investigation, Religion, and Perception.

In the PHB, you get Perception from race and you choose two from being a Wizard.  So why does the starter set pre-made character get 5 proficient skills?

Answer (score 34):

This comes from the Elf's Acolyte Background.

From BD&D:

> Proficiencies: Insight, Religion (p37)

So here's how this breaks down.

- Elf: Perception
- Acolyte: Insight, Religion
- Wizard: Arcana, Investigation

That is now you get to 5 skills.

It's important to note that *most* characters will get skill proficiencies from their race, class *and* background.

Comment: There are plenty of races that do not grant skill proficiencies. It is true, however, that all classes and backgrounds each grant 2 skill proficiencies.

Answer (score 7):

Each Background grants you two skill proficiencies (as well as other things). One skill from being an Elf, two skills from being a Wizard, and two skills for the character's Background makes five total.